# Running a Python script in Wordpress

Tags: php, python, wordpress

I'm a newbie to Python and am trying to run a very simple Python script within Wordpress. I have followed the answers to [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120259/running-a-python-script-within-wordpress) question but without luck.

First I created and activated a Wordpress plugin using the following php:

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/* Plugin Name: Python embedded */

add_shortcode( 'python', 'embed_python' );

function embed_python( $attributes )
{
    $data = shortcode_atts(
        [
            'file' => 'firstpython.py'
        ],
        $attributes
    );

    $handle = popen( __DIR__ . '/' . $data['file'], 'r' );
    $read = '';

    while ( ! feof( $handle ) )
    {
        $read .= fread( $handle, 2096 );
    }

    pclose( $handle );

    return $read;
}
```

I saved the firstpython.py file in the plugin's folder which looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print ("It works!")
```

I have verified that /usr/bin/python is the correct location through SSH.

Finally, I inserted the `[python]` shortcode into a Wordpress page. But when I go to that page, there is no output at all, but no errors either.

If it makes a difference, I am using 1and1's Managed Wordpress hosting. Does anybody know where I am going wrong? I'm probably just making a rookie's mistake somewhere.

Footnote: I'm a data analyst, not a programmer, so apologies if I have misunderstood the mechanics of what I'm trying to achieve. I'm very familiar with R but installing R on a server is beyond me, hence the move to Python. I might be out of my depth here as well.

Comment: Is error reporting enabled?  popen may be disabled on many shared hosts.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments of the question you posted, depending on the machine that it is running on you might need to add `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the beginning of your python script. And it seems that the first line of your script is different.